# Discretize chart in a given interval

Tags: graphics, numerics, discretization

Using the following code:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
points = Cases[plot // Normal, Line[{x__}] -> x, Infinity];
ListPlot[points]
```

I get:

[image]

Question: Is it possible to thicken such discretization? Also, you can do so at any given internal interval to the graph?

Thank you for your invaluable help.

---

EDIT:

To be honest I was wrong example, I try again.

```
plot = Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]];
points = Cases[plot // Normal, Line[{x__}] -> x, Infinity];
ListPlot[points]
```

Here, in the latter case there is any hope to increase the points in a given interval, for example, in [-1,1]? Thanks again and sorry for my incompetence.

Comment: "Thicken"? You mean, like increase the number of points? Try adding `PlotPoints -> 200` or something to the `Plot` function: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 200]`. As for doing it in particular intervals, you can always make multiple plots with different `PlotPoints`, and then `Show` them all together on one plot.

Comment: You can control exactly the points plotted by creating the table yourself `ListPlot[Table[{x,Sin[x]},{x,-Pi,Pi,2*Pi/(n-1)}]]` where `n` is the number of points you want.

Comment: "increase the points in a given interval" - what do you need it for?

Comment: Maybe you would like `Interpolation[points]`? Look up the documentation for [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here one option is to add new points to increase density in a `range`.

The `pointsInitial` list is the values ​​you have in your `points` list.
I've created a new list that creates new points for your `given interval`.

The [`Subdivide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html) function controls how many points you want in the minimum and maximum limits.
Then two controls were created for number of points.

The [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) function joins these two lists

The [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html) function organizes the values ​​in ascending order

The [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) function can delete duplicate values.

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
pointsInitial = Flatten@{{#}, {Sin[#]}} & /@ Subdivide[-Pi, Pi, 100];
pointsAdditional = Flatten@{{#}, {Sin[#]}} & /@ Subdivide[-1, 1, 45];
ListPlot[DeleteDuplicates[Sort@Join[pointsInitial, pointsAdditional]],
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: IMAGEM]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Mesh` as follows:

```
mesh = Join[Subdivide[-Pi, -1, 20],  Subdivide[-1, 1, 50], Subdivide[1,Pi, 20]]

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi},  
 Mesh -> {mesh}, MeshStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In version 9 or earlier versions, you can define `mesh` using `Range` instead of `Subdivide` as follows:

```
mesh = Join @@ Range[{-Pi, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, Pi}, {(-1 + Pi)/20, 2/50, (Pi - 1)/20}]
```

Also (thanks: @MichaelE2 ):

```
ListPlot@Transpose@{mesh, Sin@mesh}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Also `ListPlot@Transpose@{mesh, Sin@mesh}`, plus styling as desired.

Comment: @Michael, thank you. I updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a function `density[x]` which is proportional to the desired density of the sampling near `x`, then the following is a way to generate samples with the desired variable density:

```
Clear[x, t];
interval = {-Pi, Pi};
density[x_] :=     (* NDSolve does not detect the discontinuities in Piecewise here *)
  Simplify`PWToUnitStep@Piecewise[{{3, -1 <= x <= 1}}, 1];   (* convert to UnitStep *)
samplingIFN = NDSolveValue[
   {x'[t] == 1/density[x[t]], x[0] == interval[[1]],
    WhenEvent[x[t] == interval[[2]], "StopIntegration"]},
   x, {t, 0, Infinity}];

domain = First@samplingIFN["Domain"];
xx = samplingIFN@Subdivide[Sequence @@ domain, 100];
ListPlot[Transpose@{xx, Sin@xx}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want a more even distribution of mesh points, another possibility is to use the "ArcLength" mesh function:

```
Plot[
    Sin[x], {x,-Pi,Pi},
    PlotStyle->None, MeshStyle->Blue, Mesh->100, MeshFunctions->{"ArcLength"}
]
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants "to increase the points in a given interval, for example, in [-1,1]", i.e., increase the density.  But since @Manu didn't accept any of those answers, maybe we're wrong.